# Why do humans rule Mushroom Kingdom?

Tags: video-games, super-mario-brothers

[image: Princess Peach]

By all means, Princess Peach looks human. So, her father should also be human.

Citizens of Mushroom Kingdom are Toads (colorful toads) and maybe, Yoshis (colorful Yoshis). Why would humans rule it? What's the back story of it?

Comment: She became ruler of the Mouse Kingdom by common agreement; https://www.mariowiki.com/images/d/df/AMouserintheHouser.jpg

Comment: Are we *sure* the Toads aren't humans wearing elaborate clothing that gives them a mushroom-like appearance?  The wiki seems to *assume* they are a separate species, but I couldn't find any direct quote establishing that they aren't human.  (I could very well be wrong, given the absolutely stunning volume of canon material to sift through, but like I said, the wiki doesn't seem to call out an explicit reference establishing this "fact.")

Comment: @Steve-O - It's pretty clear that Princess Peach and the King are humans whereas the "Toads" are not. We see female Toads in later episodes as well as in the cartoon and comic series; https://www.mariowiki.com/images/9/97/ToadMissiontoSavePeach.jpg

Comment: Maybe the Toads are actually their worlds version of furries.

Comment: Maybe imperialism?

Comment: I Love You - I think that you might as well ask why the Russian princes in the late middle ages all paid tribute to a ruler whose family came from Mongolia, or why the royal family that ruled from Mexico to Argentina in 1600 originally ruled a part of what is now Switzerland, or why in 1762 the Tsar of Russia was the Duke of Holstein-Gottorp and the Empress was a princess of Anhalt-Zerbst.

Comment: Yoshis are animals and live in Dinosaur Land.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be a case of [Anthropomorphic Zig-Zag](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnthropomorphicZigZag) with the Princess (and her father) becoming dramatically more human-like and the Toads becoming dramatically more mushroom-like as the game series progressed.

In the original depictions (in the [How to Win at Super Mario Bros. gamebook](https://www.emuparadise.me/magazine-comic-guide-scans/How_to_Win_at_Super_Mario_Bros/1797), for example), the Mushroom king and Princess Toadstool are shown to be much more like mushrooms with the guards appearing to be at least partially human.

> [image]

Later games explained the difference by having the the Mushroom-loving (human) people of the Mushroom Kingdom transformed into Mushrooms.

> [image]
>   <sub><sup>[Super Mario Bros. Deluxe - Manual](http://www.gamesdatabase.org/Media/SYSTEM/Nintendo_Game_Boy_Color/Manual/formated/Super_Mario_Bros._Deluxe_-_1999_-_Nintendo.pdf)</sup></sub>
>
> *"These terrible terrapins transformed the peace-loving Mushroom people into stones, bricks, and ironically mushrooms, then set their own evil king on the throne"*

---

As to the *specific* reason why the inhabitants of the spectacularly multicultural Mushroom Kingdom would choose the Mushroom King and his daughter as their rulers, the very simple answer seems to be that they alone possess the magical power needed to control the enemy on their borders, the evil Kooper.

For the record, we see at least one other instance where a "kingdom" *under* the Mushroom Kingdom chooses to make Peach (and by extension her father) their ruler by common acclamation in the Mario comic "[A Mouser in the Houser](https://www.mariowiki.com/A_Mouser_in_the_Houser)"

[image]

Comment: When I google "Why is Princess Peach human", Google excerpt of Princess Peach Wikipedia page displays that one grandmother of Princess Peach is toad and one grandmother is human. So, this is more than `Anthropomorphic Zig-Zag`. There seems a very deep back story which I am unable to find.

Comment: @ILoveYou - This appears to be a misunderstanding. The term "grandma" used in the Mario RPG [appears to be an honorific](https://www.mariowiki.com/Grandma) rather than an indication of familial relationship. She's *a* grandma, not her grandma. We see one of her grandparents in the Cartoon series. She is, as expected, human; https://www.mariowiki.com/Gramma_Toadstool

Comment: Quoting Wikipedia: `She also has a grandmother who is a Toad and a grandmother who is a human, implying that she may be part-Toad.` Is this wrong?

Comment: @ILoveYou - Yes. See the links in my comment. The Mushroom grandmother may or may not be her real grandmother, and probably isn't. The translation is from "*Obāsan*" which can mean grandmother, but usually just means "Old lady" (in a respecful way).

Comment: @Valorum When is it ever respectful to call a woman old?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - There are shades of meaning in Japanese that don't really translate to English. You might refer to someone as your brother, uncle or mother without having any relation to them. It's more like you're calling them *someone's* brother, uncle or mother.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd In English, it's not. But you have to remember that these are Japanese games, and any English we get is a (usually poor) translation. It's not going to 100% match the original intent, hence all the confusion. I guarantee you Japanese fans are not confused about this stuff. It all makes perfect sense to them.