# Is there a real King (or Queen) of the Sugar Rush Kingdom?

Tags: wreck-it-ralph

In Wreck-it Ralph, Vanellope is confirmed to be the *Princess* of Sugar Rush. This would imply that she’s either the daughter of a King and/or Queen or that she, as supreme ruler of the Kingdom should *be* the Queen.

It occurred to me that the Kingdom might actually be a [principality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality) (albeit one ruled by a princess) but **is there anything that explains her status?**

Comment: Are you asking if there's any in-universe evidence that this is a Principality as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality?

Comment: She could also be the grand-daughter of a reigning monarch or (as of 2012 in the UK) the great-grand-daughter.

Comment: This seems to be attracting downvotes because it starts with an unfounded assumption. I've done a big edit to try to make it less guess-work-y and more focused.

Comment: Thanks @Valorum, that seems to make the question better. Hopefully it will stem the tide of downvotes (or that new downvoters would comment on how this question can be further improved).

Comment: @Thunderforge - There's still a confusing number of close votes being cast. I suspect that there's a bit of less-than-careful reviewing going on here

Comment: I like to think she's the patron of the race, and so King Candy, if he existed at all, wasn't relevant until "he" showed up.

Comment: I simply want to point out that, as a video game reference, it would not be unusual to have a Kingdom ruled by a princess. It could very easily be a reference to the Mushroom Kingdom, which is officially ruled by Princess Peach--though she seems to delegate any actual governance to chancellors and such.

Comment: @trlkly - Princess Peach may be the de facto ruler, but her father (The Mushroom King) is still very much alive; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156294/why-do-humans-rule-mushroom-kingdom

Comment: @Thunderforge - Quick edit and the votes come rolling in. SE loves an on-topic question.

Comment: @Mike Scott  Actually there are a few examples in history of monarchs living to be  not just grandparents or great grandparents but great great grandparents.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Yes, but under UK law as it stands at present, none of a reigning monarch’s great-great-grandchildren are princes or princesses. Only their children and some (not all) of their grand-children and great-grand-children.

Comment: It's worth noting that Frozen is an example of a Disney Kingdom which, for a time, has two princesses and no reigning king or queen. Presumably the Frozen sisters had some kind of regent who ruled in their stead until one of them came of age, but who was considered insignificant enough that they didn't warrant any real screen time, so it's feasible this is also the state of the kingdom in Sugar Rush. Sour Bill was meant to be Vanellope's assistant, so perhaps he was the _de facto_ regent.

Answer (score 20):

The very short answer is that world of Sugar Rush isn't a fully formed society that has grown and evolved over time. It's basically a *snapshot* of a community that was created by its *in-universe writers* as the setting for a series of races that take place within a small (and ill-defined) society presided over by a Princess. In short, there never was a real King Candy since the society was birthed, **fully-formed** with Princess Vanellope as its absolute ruler.

> **Q. Was King Candy an existing character in the game, or did Turbo create him from scratch?**
>
> **[Raymond S. Persi](http://archive.is/20130624162232/raymondsp.tumblr.com/post/44901642286/was-king-candy-an-existing-character-in-the-game-or#selection-21.0-21.7):** Good question. I think **King Candy didn’t exist before Turbo got there.** That’s why Vanellope was on the side and the ruler of the world.

and

> **Q. is that answer regarding King Candy 100% canon or just your own personal theory?**
>
> [**Raymond S. Persi**](http://archive.is/20130624162311/raymondsp.tumblr.com/post/45034233647/is-that-answer-regarding-king-candy-100-canon-or-just#selection-89.1-105.169): That’s what we were going for. **Turbo snuck into Sugar Rush, created a new persona in the form of King Candy** and reprogrammed everyone to think he had always been around.